# Environment-specific externalizing properties file(s) in Spring Boot

Tags: deployment, spring-boot, environment-variables, configuration-management

I have a Spring Boot app that runs as a jar via the following script (excerpted):

```
SERVICE_NAME=submit-enrollment
PID_PATH_NAME=~/submit-enrollment/application.pid
PATH_TO_JAR=~/submit-enrollment/submit-enrollment-1.0.0.jar
JVM_OPTS="-Xmx1g"
SPRING_OPTS="--logging.file=submit-enrollment-1.0.0.log"

case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java $JVM_OPTS -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null $SPRING_OPTS &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;; .........
```

Configuration property files (2 for now: **application.properties** and **submit-enrollment.properties**) reside inside the above jar file  in the app root and the property values from them are read into various beans via @PropertySource and @Value annotations, for example:

**submit-enrollment.properties:**

```
marshaller.contextPaths=c.f.e.a_e.e_1, c.f.e.a._1
default.Uri=https://i.h.c.com/I1/AEService  
soap.action=http://wsdl.business.services.ee.ffe.c.h.com/AEPT/CAMIPR
auditLog.server=10.172.x.xx
auditLog.port=8062
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.main.show-banner=false
server.port=9278
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.core = DEBUG
logging.level.com.sun.xml.internal.messaging = DEBUG
#logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing = TRACE
#logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received = TRACE
```

=================================

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"c.f.e", "c.z.submit.enrollment"})
@PropertySource("classpath:/submit-enrollment.properties")
public class SubmitEnrollmentConfig {

    @Value("${marshaller.contextPaths}")
    private String[] marshallerContextPaths;

    @Value("${default.Uri}")
    private String defaultUri;
```

==================================

```
@Service("soapClient")
public class FmfSoapClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

@Value("${soap.action}")
private String soapAction;


@Value("${auditLog.server}")
private String auditLogServer;

@Value("${auditLog.port}")
private String auditLogPort;
```

As application grows, other .properties files will be added, probably something along the lines of used spring components, i.e. security.properties, web-services.properties, web-properties, etc. vs a single submit-enrollment.properties file.

That's the current setup.  What I'm looking for is the following:

**Question:**

I'd like to be able to have the .properties files become externalized to reside somewhere on the file system **outside of the jar file** as well as have them named in a manner reflecting the **environment**:

```
application-dev.properties
submit-enrollment-dev.properties
```

;;;;

```
application-uat.properties
submit-enrollment-uat.properties
```

;;;

```
application-prod.properties
submit-enrollment-prod.properties
```

I'd like to pass Spring Boot a parameter in the shell script telling which environment I'm running it in:

```
java -jar submit-enrollment.jar -environment=uat
```

and have Spring automatically resolve the proper properties files based on their -env- value that would correspond to the parameter above.  Is that something that currently exists as part of Spring Boot functionality, if so could someone please point me to some sample setup like that.  If that is, in your opinion, not a viable approach, perhaps instead of having .properties files with different name resolved by Spring it would be better to segregate them into an environment specific directory while letting them have the same name across the environments, should I resort to doing it in Maven or Jenkins instead of having Spring Boot do it at run time?  Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to change both the name of the file and have Spring Boot pick up automatically the environment that you have specified.

Spring Boot supports [profile specific properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) out-of-the-box. So if you enable the `uat` profile, it will look up for a `application-uat.properties` in the usual locations.

If you don't like `application` as a prefix, you can specify the `SPRING_CONFIG_NAME` system/os property [to define a different name](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

If that does not work for you, you can use `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` to tell Spring Boot where to look for things. You can then list either directories or individual files. That last property gives you maximum flexibility and should probably meet your requirements but it's more work on your end.

Comment: Thanks.  If I merge all configuration properties from both classpath:/submit-enrollment.properties and application.properties into application.properties and use --spring.config.location=./application.properties when calling a jar then the behavior seems to be to disregard @PropertySource("classpath:/submit-enrollment.properties") annotation altogether.    So if finer granularity of the .properties files is desired I just need to use multiple .properties files in a directory pointed at by '--spring.config.location=' flag, right?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with `./`. As I said already _The problem is that you want to change both the name of the file and have Spring Boot pick up automatically the environment that you have specified._ If you want to load multiple files in a directory, you need to specify them via the `spring.config.location` property yes. Spring Boot will _not_ scan a whole directory for all `.properties` files.

Comment: Stephane Nicoll, can you answer this pls ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034087/spring-boot-not-reading-environment-specific-yaml-file?noredirect=1#comment69282349_41034087