# Spring boot not reading environment specific YAML file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have developed a spring boot rest application and I am trying to read the environment specific YAML file based on the value "**spring.profiles.active**"

I have two files

```
 1. application.yml
 2. application-qa.yml
```

and I have below property in both the files

*application.yml* file has below property

```
comp:
 bu:
  env: local
```

*application-qa.yml* file has below property

```
comp:
 bu:
  env: QA
```

and I am setting  `spring.profiles.active=qa`, given above, I was expecting that only  `application-qa.yml` gets loaded, but in this case both `application.yml and application-qa.yml` are getting loaded and when my code looks for property **comp.bu.env** it is always getting the value

> local

only

I want my code to read the **comp.bu.env** property from `application-qa.yml` file.

can some help to figure out what i am missing here?

Comment: [Profile-specific properties should overrides the non-specific ones](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties), you can add `spring-boot-starer-actuator`, and access `/env` to see whats happened to your properties.

Comment: tan9, can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: Add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to your pom.xml or build.gradle, run your application and then access http://localhost:8080/env for Environment information exposed by Spring Boot's [Endpoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html).

Comment: Thanks for your point. I have solved it and posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your points, I have solved it.
I have **AWS profile** in application-qa.yml which is **causing my QA properties to be skipped** because the profile name I have supplied is QA. I have moved my properties above the AWS:profile in application-qa.yml file then those properties started picking up.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the spring.profiles.active value is not being set correctly, and hence your app is loading the default application.yml.
Try setting the value with 
`-Dspring.profiles.active=qa`
before the `bootRun` command.

e.g. If you are using gradle, you would do `./gradlew -Dspring.profiles.active=qa bootrun`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `comp.bu.env` configuration from `application.properties`. Create separate configuration file `application-dev.yaml` and place this configuration there:

```
comp:
 bu:
  env: local
```

Now when you work on local configure `spring.profiles.active=qa`.

This would effectively create development configuration profile.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I don't have application.properties I have application.yml so I have deleted it and created application-dev.yml and configured spring.profiles.active=qa, and I am trying to bring up the application, but my application is still looking for application.yml file and failing as that file is not present. spring boot always requires application.yml file ???